# File not found - 0 File(s) copied - Batch Programming - Copying a file from one pc to another

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, xcopy

I'm trying to copy a dll file to another PC of the same network by using the batch file. But when I run the batch file, it says File not found.
Here's the code I'm using for the batch file.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ("%CD%\targets.txt") DO (
xcopy /Y "%CD%\RevitDMS.dll" "%%i"
)
pause
```

Here is the text is written in the targets.txt file:

> "\192.168.6.205\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"

here is the folder location where the batch file is located, as we can clearly see the RevitDMS.dll has located already in the same directory.

[image: Folder Where Batch File is Located]

Would appreciate if anyone helps me figure out the solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm very suspicious about *how* you are executing this batch. It doesn't appear to make sense for you to execute it from a `cmd` prompt *and* use `pause`, so I conclude that you are executing it by clicking on it. If you were to comment-out the `ECHO OFF` then you'd get a blow-by-blow account of what's happening - and I predict that `cd` in this case is `%username%\desktop`, not `revitdms\....` as you expect. If so, you'd need to `cd` (or `pushd`) to `revitdms\....` before the `for` or change the `start in` location of your shortcut. And I believe you'd need `\\192.168...`, not `\192.168...`

Comment: If you're copying to a network location, then it should either be mapped in advance or you should create a temporary mapping either with `Net Use` or `PushD / PopD`. What appears inside the text file must also be of the correct format too. I don't believe that this would be the correct command, `XCopy /Y "C:\Users\Ali\RevitDMS\publish dms batch file\RevitDMS.dll" ""\192.168.6.205\C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\""`.